# Python http.server 2 instances and 2 folders

Tags: python

I am using python http.server to init 2 instances at different ports and serve up a html file from a folder...

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import os

PORT1 = 8000
PORT2 = 8001

os.chdir("html/folder1/")
Handler1 = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

os.chdir("../folder2/")
Handler2 = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd1 = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT1), Handler1)
httpd2 = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT2), Handler2)

print("serving at port", PORT1)
print("serving at port", PORT2)

httpd1.serve_forever()
httpd2.serve_forever()
```

This loads without errors but I am only able to load http://localhost:8000

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `serve_forever` method does just that...serves http requests, and never exits.  So when you do this:

```
httpd1.serve_forever()
httpd2.serve_forever()
```

The second statement is never executed because the first never exits.  Possibly you could make this work by putting each call to `serve_forever` in a dedicated thread, and then just waiting for all threads to complete, but there may be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, the makes sense.  Just trying to make sure that is the best solution

Comment: "thread" seems to be a good hint. Here is the next hit .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401833/python-http-server-2-instances-and-2-folders.